# Set limit to data transfer/copy speed

Tags: command-line, nautilus, sd-card

On command-line and/or file managers (such as nautilus), how do we set an upper limit to data transfer/copy speed?

I haven't found anything on the manuals of `cp` or `mv`. I want to know this since I'm having problems putting files in a MicroSD cards of Class 4. Transferring small amounts is fine, but when I put up a large queue of files (like 100 files totaling 10 GB), an "input/output error" appears and then, the SD card gets locked, and I cannot delete or do anything with it. Setting a transfer speed would probably fix it.

Comment: Thanks for asking! It's interesting for my usb device too, so I added the tag :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think `scp -l 500 original /some/destination/` might me your best option.
Where:

- `-l` Limits the used bandwidth, specified in Kbit/s.

<sup>See [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)</sup>

Comment: thanks for the help! would appreciate if anyone shared a filemanager-like drag-n-drop method too. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! Also a method limiting the access to the volume across the entire system would be helpful.

Comment: Don't really think it works for local copy between storage devices. I can't see any percent-progress or byte-rate numbers, even if I launch with -v, but if I Ctrl-C to stop it as both source and destination SD cards overheat (which I was trying to avoid), I see way too much data copied vs. what the rate should've been if my -l spec had been honored.

Answer (score 1):

`scp -l` doesn't do it for me on Xubuntu 20.04, it just writes at max speed when copying from SD card to SD card.

What works for me is `rsync --bwlimit NNN`, with NNN=kilo**bytes** per second.

The limit I think is applied for the average rate over the whole transfer and may be exceeded for individual files here and there if you're looking at it with `--progress`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe through [`pv` with `-L`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv):

> `-L RATE`, `--rate-limit RATE`: Limit the transfer to a maximum of RATE bytes per second. A suffix of "k", "m", "g", or "t" can be added to denote kilobytes (*1024), megabytes, and so on.

More info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/671348/209677). Some people also mention [`trickle`](https://github.com/mariusae/trickle) (user-space bandwidth shaper).

Then, as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/610135/209677): If you need to jump through one (or more) proxy servers, [OpenSSH v7.3 onward supports a `-J`](https://superuser.com/a/1111920/500826).

Considering A → B → C, on hostA, just:

```
tar cf - file1 file_n | pv | ssh -C -J userB@hostB:portB userB@hostC -p portC 'tar xvf - -C hostC_destination_folder'
```

- Use as many hops as you want with ssh's `-J` option.
- Omit the tar's remote `-C`  to leave the files on home folder.
- Send any files at once (text or binary).
- Increase speed by compressing the stream with ssh's `-C` (or tar's `-z`). Particularly useful if the data is plain text (uncompressed).
- [**`pv`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) monitor the progress of data through a pipe. An alternative could be [`progress`](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress).

Inspired on [Florian Fida](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177837/209677) and [Dan Garthwaite's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106508/209677) answers.

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403806/209677)'s how to do it with Midnight Commander.

**Related project**: [Magic Wormhole](https://github.com/magic-wormhole/magic-wormhole): *Get things from one computer to another, safely.*